# Change RecyclerView MvvmCross for widget.RecyclerView

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a module of my app where you can answer different questions such as text, boolean, multiple selection etc...

It's built with MvvmCross RecyclerView with its adapter and its viewHolders. Basically, I've 14 viewTypes. Each one is a type of layout.

But the recyclerview of mvvmcross is giving me performance problems when I scroll, it presents a delay of about one second.

My question is: there will be some difference between the recyclerView of android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView and the one of mvvmcross besides the way of making binding to change it for that and verify if it improves the performance a bit?

Unfortunately I cannot share much code because of company policies.

Thanks for you help.

My recycler view

```xml
<MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.RecyclerView.MvxRecyclerView
 android:clipToPadding="false"
 android:id="@+id/form_rv_formitems"
 android:focusable="false"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Activity

```cs
protected override void OnViewModelSet()
{
  _recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter((IMvxAndroidBindingContext)BindingContext);
  _recyclerView = FindViewById<MvxRecyclerView>(Resource.Id.form_rv_formitems);
  _recyclerView.HasFixedSize = true;
  _recyclerView.Adapter = _recyclerViewAdapter;   
 _recyclerView.ViewTreeObserver.AddOnScrollChangedListener(this);
        }
```

My adapter

```cs
public class RecyclerViewAdapter : MvxRecyclerAdapter
    {
        public RecyclerViewAdapter(IMvxAndroidBindingContext bindingContext)
            : base(bindingContext) => HasStableIds = true;

        public override int GetItemViewType(int position) => 
            ViewTypeFactory.GetViewTypeBy((BindableFormItem)GetItem(position));

        public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            var bc = new MvxAndroidBindingContext(parent.Context, BindingContext.LayoutInflaterHolder);
            var vh = FormItemViewHolderFactory.GetByViewType(viewType, parent, bc);
            return vh;
        }

        public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            base.OnBindViewHolder(holder, position);
            var vh = holder as FormItemViewHolder;
            vh.Bind();
        }

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            var fi = (BindableFormItem)GetItem(position);
            return fi.Id;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use MvxTemplateSelector instead of creating your own Adapter for switching ViewHolder depending on either ViewModel type or some property in the ViewModel. As for performance issues, it is hard to tell you what is bogging down performance in your app with the information you have provided. However, MvvmCross mainly does stuff in `OnBindViewHolder`. What you could do is to profile your app to pinpoint the issue. If you don't have a VS Enterprise license, you can add a bunch of StopWatches around your code to figure out what is taking a long time.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Cheesebaron. Yes, I know that with little information is complicated to know what you are taking time. What I realized, was to place several Stopwatch and the method in which it later took was the `OnBindViewHolder`. I am also trying to apply `MvxTemplaSelector`, I comment as I go.

Comment: What happens in your `Bind()` method?

Comment: In my method Bind happens this:                                                                       
 `if (BindableFormItem.ParentFormItemType == ParentFormItemType.Inline)
            {
                var marginLarge = GetDimensionById(Resource.Dimension.margin_large);
                ItemView.SetPaddingRelative(marginLarge, 0, marginLarge, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                ItemView.SetPaddingRelative(PaddingStart, 0, PaddingEnd, 0);
            }`

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use MvxTemplateSelector because I have some items that are nested :-(. I'll have to see waht happens in OnBindViewHolder